# How to launch an DataStage job ETL from Java client?

Tags: java, etl, datastage

I premise that I don't know a lot about DataStage.

I just know that somebody else has created an "ETL job" and I need to launch it from my Java program, that acts as a client.

How should I do?

**Edit:**

The DataStage server is phisically different from the client where the Java program runs. I am not allowed running commans on the DataStage server. I need to connect via network. I imagined that DataStage provides some kind of network protocol, or webservice, or something so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `dsjob` command - details see the [Knowledge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSZJPZ_11.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.ds.direct.doc/topics/t_ddesref_running_job_command_line.html)

**Edit:**
dsjob needs to be executed at the server.

You could use a insert into a database table from remote and trigger something (i.e. a UDF) that executes the dsjob on the server.
Alternatively use the WaitForFile stage and transfera file to the server.

Comment: Thank you, I realized that my question was incomplete, I go and improve it.